# Rails 6 Capistrano Deploy Failing: corrupted hmac detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 6 app with Capistrano + Nginx + Puma. In the past(Rail 4 in that case) I used this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma and it worked fine.

However, when I try to run `cap production deploy:initial(or without the initial namespace)` I receive the following error: `The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 31.220.51.222: Exception while executing on host 31.220.51.222: corrupted hmac detected
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed`

So I'm not sure if it is a problem with NET::SSH and where it comes from, or if it is a problem that have nothing to do with this message.

Following is the last lines of capistrano.log with the -t option enabled.

````
 DEBUG [daa21174] Command: cd /home/deploy/apps/market_backend/releases/20200422204058 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check --path /home/deploy/apps/market_backend/shared/bundle
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [33m[DEPRECATED] The `--path` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set path '/home/deploy/apps/market_backend/shared/bundle'`, and stop using this flag[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [33mThe dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31mThe following gems are missing[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * public_suffix (4.0.4)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * addressable (2.7.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * net-ssh (6.0.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * net-scp (1.2.1)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * sshkit (1.21.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * airbrussh (1.4.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * bindex (0.8.1)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * byebug (11.1.2)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * capistrano (3.13.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * capistrano-bundler (1.6.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * capistrano-rails (1.4.0)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)[0m
 DEBUG [daa21174]   
 DEBUG [daa21174]   [31m * capistrano-yarn (2.0.2)[0m```



The strange thing is that the log suddently finishes without saying anything about the problem.

Does someone has any clue on how to solve this?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be an issue with the latest updated version of the net-ssh gem, I had the same issue, after I downgraded it works.

You find it here:

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/728

Comment: Hello @Max I managed to make it work by mixing the old tutorial with this one https://onebitcode.com/deploy-rails-digital-ocean-capistrano/ however, this doesn't make any sense for me, and still happens sometimes, I just need to try again, and again until works. I downgraded as you suggested and seems to be working as well. Thanks a lot. :D